# UIApplicationDelegate supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor not called when supported by Multitasking on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm facing an issue with the `supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor` function in my iOS app. The function is not getting called when the application is supported by the Split View screen(Multitasking).

In my app delegate, I have the following function to handle the application orientation based on a specific requirement:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    // This function is not being called when the app is in Split View
    // Need help in understanding why and how to make it work in Split View
    // Implementation here
    return self.supportedOrientationMask // Placeholder return value
}


I also have a static function in my app delegate to handle application orientation when in session, where I set the supportedOrientationMask property:

static func handleApplicationOrientationWhenInSession(rotate: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = AppDelegate.instance

    if rotate {
        // Enable rotation by setting supported orientation to all
        appDelegate?.supportedOrientationMask = .all
    } else {
        // Set the supported orientation based on the current orientation
        if let currentOrientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation {
            var value: UIInterfaceOrientationMask

            switch currentOrientation {
            case .portrait:
                value = .portrait
            case .portraitUpsideDown:
                value = .portraitUpsideDown
            case .landscapeLeft:
                value = .landscapeLeft
            case .landscapeRight:
                value = .landscapeRight
            default:
                value = .all
            }

            appDelegate?.supportedOrientationMask = value
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }

    // Attempt to rotate to the device's current orientation
    UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        if let topViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController?.topMostVisibleViewController {
            // Use 'window' for your specific needs
            print("Force orientation")
            topViewController.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
            topViewController.view.setNeedsLayout()
            topViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}


Note: If i don't configured supported orientation in Info.plist like below then it works


    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    </plist>
```